# Firebase Realtime database doesn't work after publishing android app on play store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

basically am working on an android project with firebase realtime database, so in debugging mode everything is working fine, i can read and write to firebase; but after the app is uploaded to the play store as closed testing, the app doesn't write to firebase properly, i will show you in the image ...so what i did is :
1-getting SHA-1 from app signing and add it to firebase project
2-create linked services between play store and firebase
3-remove all rules
4-update google-services.json in the app and upload again
Nothing worked
its weird... can anyone help please [please check this picture, 1->before releasing ; 2->after releasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8xaX.png)

Comment: perhaps making use of obfuscation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to code obfuscation, exclude your firebase code from code obfuscation.
Try reading this - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: Thank you for helping me, you give me the hint, the problem solved by adding this line '-keepclassmembers' in proguard-rules